# Laravel: switch works properly in one project, but crashes in another

Tags: laravel, switch-statement

the following statement

@switch($i)
    @case(1)
        First case...
        @break
    @case(2)
        Second case...
        @break
    @default
        Default case...
@endswitch

works properly in one project, but in another project the following message appears:

FatalErrorException
'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context

Laravel version is 5.6.28
Ubuntu 18.04

I'm afraid that, as the computer is rarely updated, when I updated something crashed in Laravel

Comment: Check your /storage/framework/views folder for the compiled view to check what kind of markup it generated. It should give you hints as to what went wrong.

Comment: the interpreter is ignoring @switch. The code is:      @switch($tipo)
    @case(1)  
        First case...  
        <?php break; ?>. As you see, it is missing <$php switch ?>

Comment: Double check that the correct laravel version is installed in both projects. Switch was added in Laravel 5.5 so if one project is at say 5.4 then it will produce this exact behaviour

Comment: probably you are right.  the current version is 5.6 but, as I created the project some time ago, the version could be 5.4 or lower. In this case, how could I fix the problem?

Comment: If you have 5,4 then follow the steps in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0) , if it's even lower then you may need to upgrade in steps e.g. if you have 5.3 then upgrade to 5.4 and then 5.5. Mostly you don't actually need to do much besides updating your dependencies ,but there's a few things that may not be backwards compatible

Comment: apokryfos, you were right! the version was 5.4. Now it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try @breakswitch

@switch($i)
    @case(1)
       First case...
        @breakswitch
    @case(2)
      Second case...
        @breakswitch
   @default
Default case...

@endswitch

Answer (score 0):

I checked my /storage/framework/views folder.
@breakswitch gives no error, but the problem is still the same: the interpreter does not recognize the command @switch, so my web page shows the following:
@case(1) First case... @breakswitch @case(2) Second case... @breakswitch @default Default case... @endswitch